# Text Wrap in<Run> tag in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Sai"></Run>
    <Run Text="aaaaa"></Run>
    <Run Text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"></Run>
    <Run Text="zzzzz"></Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Above code, I just want to wrap the text for fourth '' tag. Is to possible to wrap only one run tag of the TextBlock?

Comment: you should try using a `TextBlock` instead of your Run, then you can set some fixed width for that TextBlock and use `TextWrapping` property.

Comment: Thanks @KingKing, But i want to use grid row as well as column for textblock. So i want use all four runs which are binded to different properties. I just want is it possible to give width for run. If it is not possible, i will use textblock.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to set some width and wrapping text of a Run (as well as other Inline elements). Wrapping text is something not simple, I believe the internal implemented code is fairly complex about this. There are just some controls supporting this feature such as TextBlock, AccessText or maybe some other ones...